# How to send json data from the backend (express.js) to the frontend (react) after res.status(404)?

Tags: reactjs, express, error-handling, try-catch, backend

I am making a react login app connected to an express server and everything works fine and now I am trying to handle errors.
When the user sends username and password I check on express if the user exists in the db, and if it doesn't then I set the status at 404 and send json error that I want to grab in the front end to display that error in an alert.
The problem is that even though in the frontend I am getting the 404 error, the json array of message doesn't appear.
This is my code:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // check if user exists
  const user = await User.findOne({ username });
  console.log('user: ', user);
  // if the user doesn't exst
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      erros: [
        {
          msg: 'No user found',
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

And this is the error I am getting:

[image]

Any idea why the array of error is not sent to the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume you are using axios in frontend, that will fall to `.catch`, so it will be like this

```
axios.post(...).catch((error) => {
console.log(error.response.data) // <- that's your response data
});
```

your code works, just wrong way to catch at frontend

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code to send json object along with status code 404

```
res.status(404).send({
  erros: [
    {
      msg: 'No user found',
    },
  ],
});
```